# Deserialize JSON into object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have received following json in response:

```
{
  "CreateCustomerResponse": {
    "ServiceContextType": {
      "Status": {
        "MessageType": "SUCCESS",
        "Message": "Wow! You qualified"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to `deserialize` it and manipulate the value of `Message` and `serialize` it again. How can I do this? Please excuse me if its a stupid question but I am a beginner and I don't have much knowledge of json. 
I tried this:

```
List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(responseString);
```

But got Exception:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[InfluxDB.Serie]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'results', line 2, position
>   12."}

Comment: Did you even try to figure out how to deserialise JSON? There's literally thousands of questions on here.

Comment: As for the edit, what makes you think this JSON would deserialise into a `List<string[]>`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like (thanks to [JsonToC#](http://json2csharp.com/)):

```
public class Status
{
   public string messageType { get; set; }
   public string message { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceContextType
{
   public Status status { get; set; }
}

public class CreateCustomerResponse
{
    public ServiceContextType serviceContextType { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public CreateCustomerResponse createCustomerResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseString);
```

Comment: JsonToC# outputs PascalCase property names..?

Comment: The type names are exactly the same as the original json. I changed the property names (not the type) to have the first letter lower to get it correctly colored in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these models class to sterilize it

```
public class CustomerResponse
{
public string CreateCustomerResponse {get;set;}
public CustomContext ServiceContextType {get;set;}
}

public class CustomContext 
{
public CustomStatus Status{get;set;}
}

public class CustomStatus 
{
public string Message{get;set;}
public string MessageType{get;set;}
}
```